# Can I change my animal companion?

Tags: ranger, animal-companions

So, my animal companion, a panther, got taken into a different plane of existence by a fiend. According to my DM I don't know if its dead or not, which means I don't know if I can simply get a new one. I'm a ranger and I've never heard about changing animal companions, and my other DM friend doesn't know about any rules in regards to changing animal companions that are possibly alive.

So here's my question, is it possible to simply release the bond I had with my panther and just get a new animal companion?

Comment: Which game & version are you playing? There's a different answer for quite a few.

Comment: (Also, don't worry about the question being put on hold; it's just until you edit it with a game/version, and then we'll gladly reopen it and help you. We just don't want to give you an answer that isn't useful to you)